# how to get required input fields

Tags: html

How do I get required input fields?

thanks

```html
<input type="text" name="name">
```

Comment: This question is ambiguous: do you want to know how to make input fields as required? do you want to know how to select/get all the input fields that are required in code? Do you refer in front-end or back-end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple solution:

```html
<input type="text" name="name" required>
```

Comment: Please note that people can remove the `required` attribute, and therefor bypass this. If you want to be absolutely safe people don't mess with required fields you'll have to use a server side control (don't know what you're using, but PHP or Java would do the trick).

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML  input required attribute

**example**

```
<input type="text"name="foo"value=""required>
```

**also 
[take a look at HTML Required Attribute Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)**

Comment: Please note that people can remove the required attribute, and therefor bypass this. If you want to be absolutely safe people don't mess with required fields you'll have to use a server side control (don't know what you're using, but PHP or Java would do the trick). Also, wouldn't always link the w3schools, they aren't really that good of a source ;)

Comment: Adding to what Bono said, `required` may not be supported by some browsers (and/or their older versions).