# Bootstrap form get true or false if form is valid or not then ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Now before i ask the actual question this is a stupid rant. I swear I hate javascript and everything that is associated with it.

Now actual question.
I have a asp.net web form. I can send data to my web api controller via asp.net code and its working. I'm trying to now post the data via client side ajax using jquery, but I can't get a simple true or false if the form is valid or not. Its a bootstrap v3 form. Someone please help me get off this wild ride. I've searched countless questions but no its not working. Everything is working including post and return message, just this stupid little thing wont't

I just wish to know how to get the form validity status before i ajax. Simple.

Edit:
this button click event works.

```html
$("#additional").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/data",
        data: $('form.form-horizontal').serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                swal(msg,"Success","success");
            },
        error: function(){
        swal("failure");
        }
    });
});
```

Basically I want the above ajax to run ONLY when form is valid. I have 'required' tags on my form fields already.

Comment: What do you mean of form valid or not ? e.g email validation ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that, I don't have custom validation, just a 'required' tag. so the fields only need to be not empty.

Comment: Are you sure search countless questions ?!
here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676055/how-to-get-required-input-fields

Comment: Please read my question again.

Comment: Sorry,I dont really understand what you mean of validation! why check validation of your form before trigger ajax ?

Comment: Ok, I'll explain, I am trying to post the form data by ajax and getting a return string, without redirecting the page. But before that I want to check if the form is valid, as in the user has filled all the form values. If the user missed an item, it will not do the ajax, and I then I can send the user an error alert.

Comment: So, You can use Javascript for check validation you want. e.g check if all value items filled! Although its better check values are not empty onn server side by sending values to your ajax and check length of values! if a value is emply, return false from server to your ajax.

Comment: Please share your HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Question is not clear, but if you mean there is some inputs that they shouldn't be null or empty and after valid theme call ajax you can do some thing like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal"> <input type="text" required class="SubscribeText" name="email"> <input type="button" class="postmethod" value="Send"></form>

$(".postmethod").click(function() {
if ($(".SubscribeText").val().length>0) {

           $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/data",
    data: $('form.form-horizontal').serialize(),
        success: function(msg){
            swal(msg,"Success","success");
        },
    error: function(){
    swal("failure");
    }
});      
}
```

});

if you have some inputs, the best practice is use flag, for on click flag=true, which input fails the validation should change the flag to false then if flag is true call ajax method.

Comment: Thank you:) Yup this is what I needed, I was doing it the wrong way

Comment: your welcome :), but please vote up the answer which helps other people find solution easily